# Inserting Data in columns corresponding to data in other column

Tags: mysql, merge, insert, sql-update, toad

I have 2 Tables: Table A and Table B

Table A has below columns:
ID, Name, Address, Mobile_No, DOB
ID column in table A is already populated. Rest of the columns are blank.

Table B has below columns:
ID, Name, Address, Roll_Number

Table C has below columns:
Roll_Number, Mobile_no, DOB

I want to write SQl query to populate Name & Address (from table B) Mobile_no and DOB from Table C corresponding to the ID in Table A.

I tried using the Insert query, but it inserts a new record rather then updating the existing record.
I also used the merge into and Update query, but still it enters new record.

Can someone please provide me with a query to sort this issue?

Comment: `INSERT` is for creating a new record, `UPDATE` is for updating existing records. Use `UPDATE` with `JOIN` to update based on related rows in another table.

Comment: Hi Barmar, are you the owner of stackoverflow? if yes, request you to block my account. If no.. request you to shut your mouth if you cant help me.. I already tried a lot of googling but cannot paste the code as it involves confidential information. So mind your own business and if you are not free, don't comment..